# Append options to select and set selected option

Tags: javascript

I am programmatically creating a `select`-element with a few options. I want to make a specific option selected. For this I use `option.selected = true`. I also tried `option.selected = 'selected'`.

This is my code:

```
let select_menu_for_sequence = document.createElement("select");
select_menu_for_sequence.classList.add("sequence");


for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = i;

    if (i == 2) {
        option.selected = true;
    }

    select_menu_for_sequence.appendChild(option);
}

console.log(select_menu_for_sequence.outerHTML)
```

Output:

```
<select class="sequence">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Expected output:

```
<select value="2" class="sequence">
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

I really can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does `option.defaultSelected = true;` works?

Comment: You could try `option.setAttribute('selected', true)`

Comment: I think that there's been an assumption that a `selected` attribute MUST exist... this does not appear to be true, most of the answers to this questions does not actually add an attribute to the rendered code - yet the second option is selected. If you're only after the attribute in the outerHtml, then use `option.setAttribute("selected", true)` or `defaultSelected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setAttribute() method. It just takes two arguments: the attribute you want to add and its value.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = i;

    if (i == 2) {
        option.setAttribute('selected','');
    }

    select_menu_for_sequence.appendChild(option);
}
```

or

```
option.setAttribute('selected','true');
```

Answer (score 3):

### Update

In order to see "selected" in HTML use an attribute method instead of treating it like a property with dot notation.

```
select.options[2].toggleAttribute("selected");
```

Using dot notation on `selected` makes it a property which doesn't show in HTML yet it is evident that `.option[2]` has been selected.

```
select.options.selectedIndex = 2;
```

I think you neglected to append the select to `<body>` or anything on the document.

```js
const select = document.createElement("select");
select.classList.add("sequence");
document.body.append(select);

for (let i=1; i < 5; i++) {
  let option = document.createElement("option")
  option.textContent = i
  select.append(option);
}

//select.options.selectedIndex = 2;
select.options[2].toggleAttribute("selected");
console.log(select.outerHTML);
```

Comment: That's the output `<select class="sequence"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select>`, where's the `selected` attribute?

Comment: @Agent327 IC, updated thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
let select_menu_for_sequence = document.createElement("select");
select_menu_for_sequence.classList.add("sequence");

for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)

    select_menu_for_sequence.options[select_menu_for_sequence.options.length]=new Option(i, i);
    
    if (i == 2)
        select_menu_for_sequence.options[select_menu_for_sequence.options.length]=new Option(i, i,true,true);

console.log(select_menu_for_sequence)
```

Comment: It would be amazing if you add an explanation for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the `<select>` element to the value of the selected option.

```
select_menu_for_sequence.value = 2;
```